# Navigation.startTabBasedApp on android gives error after upgrading react-native to 0.59.3

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build, wix-react-native-navigation

I Recently upgraded my react native version to 0.59.3 and now i get an error at Navigation.startTabBasedApp() :

console error:Error while starting app: Exception in host function 
(see screenshot)

i was at react-native version 0.55.4 before and react-native-navigation version : 1.1.458

The code worked and still works flawlessly on ios but after upgrading throws an error on android.

Is upgrading to RNN v2 the only solution?
does react native v 0.59.3 not support RNN v1?
Any suggestions?

tried installing different versions of react-native-navigation v1.
code changes

```
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
      tabs: [
        {
          label: "home",
          screen: "screen1",
          title: "Modules",
          icon: icon,
          navigatorStyle: {
            navBarHidden: false,
            navBarBlur: false,
            navBarTextColor: "#000",
            navBarBackgroundColor: 'green',
          }
        },
        {
          label: "settings",
          screen: "screen2",
          title: "Profile",
          icon: iconsMap.user
        }
      ]
```

As it works on ios, the same result should be expected on android[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please update react-native-navigation to 1.1.484 or 1.1.486. Also, you can try to create a new project on RN 0.59.3 from scratch, add react-native-navigation there and check if it will work.

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP, and upgrading react-native-navigation to 1.1.486 didn't work, the error is still there.

Comment: check your code, my project after upgrading to 0.59.3 running without any issues on react-native-navigation 1.1.486

Comment: well, “check your code” isn’t very helpful, is it...?

Comment: @webeno any luck finding a solution?

Comment: @ShreevatsaAcharya The whole thing came from an issue experienced following the recent iOS 12.2 release / upgrade. The original issue was `objc[29733]: Swift class extensions and categories on Swift classes are not allowed to have +load methods` reported in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24139 - My temporary solution, for now, is to only apply the patch (I know, not a good practice, but I needed my app to work as actual users were using it): https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/df7ea6731367df4d24cda316f8b376a26da2e06c

Comment: @webeno i have no issues on ios(works flawlessly there), on android it breaks (as shown in OP)when i load a page having bottom tabs using Navigation.startTabBasedApp() .